# How to test the significance of contribution of a variable in Factor analysis and what is the resonable rule for removing a variable from FA?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, confirmatory-factor

My question is about the credibility from the statistical point of view of what I have seen in some papers where the researchers (non-statistician) define some kind of staged factor analysis (FA) and in each step they look for the variable(s) and its loading on the common factors. Then they build a rule which says if *all* loading of a variable(s) falls below a pre-considered threshold defined by the researchers (let's say 0.6), then such variable(s) are at once excluded from the analysis, and the next step FA is done on remaining variables. This so-called staged factor analysis continues until no more variable finds eligible for removal from the list of variables.
We know that L, i.e matrix of loading is equal to Cov(X,F) where L_ij is the loading of the ith variable on the jth factor.
My questions are

1. does the above-described method make sense statistically?
2. if not how we can criticize the method from the statistical point of view.
3. if we assume those who apply the above described "staged FA" feel themselves in the context of descriptive statistics (although they use samples from a population and then extend the results to the population), removing variables at once with L_ij<TRESHOLD is correct since we know even we can remove variables one by one as we do in stepwise regression according to partial p-values. what could be the reasonable rule here to select the variable to be removed first, maybe the one with lower SUM(L_ij^2)?
4. from an inferential statistics point of view, It seems excluding the variable Xi from the list of FA analysis is possible if we can somehow
   test statistically and simultaneously if H0: L_ij=0 for all j's.
   Do you know a good reference ( data-oriented) that helps me to learn about the details of "stepwise FA"?

Comment: From the point of FA itself there is no reason to remove variables at all (unless some are so tightly correlate that look like almost duplicates). But people do remove (select, remove, bring in back) variables when they _develop questionnaires/tests_ by means of FA. The reason is that they (usually) want to keep only indicators each well loaded by single factor. Then, logically, variables loaded relatively weakly and evenly by all the factors are not good candidates to constitute a "simple structure".

Comment: One problem, however, is that after removing some variables and re-doing FA the factor _rotation_ can spread loadings differently for the items left in the basket. This may suggest to return some thrown variables back.

Comment: Removing a variable with low communality (`sum(Lij^2`) is possible and is reasonable if you want to keep only variables highly loaded by one or more factors. Still, sometimes, in questionnaites, we see a variable moderately loaded by just one factor and weakly loaded by all the others as a valuable item. Overall communality of such item is not pronounced.